# Ngx-translate giving 404 error Nativescript angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, ngx-translate

I'm using Ngx-translate with Nativescript-Angular.
The reason why I'm using ngx-translate is that I need to be able to change the language during runtime.

The error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:4002:0:ERROR{ 
   "headers":{ 
      "normalizedNames":{ 

      },
      "lazyUpdate":null,
      "headers":{ 

      }
   },
   "status":404,
   "statusText":"ERROR",
   "url":"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A1B491BE-90BB-4C1E-BF1D-48C6BC398167/Library/Application Support/LiveSync/app/assets/i18n/ko-KR.json",
   "ok":false,
   "name":"HttpErrorResponse",
   "message":"Http failure response for /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A1B491BE-90BB-4C1E-BF1D-48C6BC398167/Library/Application Support/LiveSync/app/assets/i18n/ko-KR.json: 404 ERROR",
   "error":"Not Found"
}
```

Folder structure:

> - src
>
>   - app
>
>     - app.module.ts
>   - assets
>
>     - i18n
>   - class
>
>     - custom-translation.handler.ts
>   - factories
>
>     - http-loader.factories.ts

app.module.ts

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            missingTranslationHandler: {
                provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
                useClass: CustomTranslationHandler
            }
        })
```

custom-translation.handler.ts

```
import { MissingTranslationHandler, MissingTranslationHandlerParams } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';


export class CustomTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
    handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams): string | Observable<string> {
        const defaultContext = '@COMMON';
        const missingContext = 'TRANSLATE:';
        const translationKeyArray = params.key.split('.');

        if (
            translationKeyArray[0] === defaultContext ||
            translationKeyArray[1] === missingContext
        ) {
            return params.key;
        }

        translationKeyArray[0] = defaultContext;
        const newTranslationKey = translationKeyArray.join('.');
        return params.translateService
            .get(newTranslationKey, params.interpolateParams)
            .pipe(
                map(v => (v === newTranslationKey ? missingContext + params.key : v))
            );
    }
}
```

http-loader.factories.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function httpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Example translation in a component:

`<Button text="{{ tc + '.CONFIRM' | translate }}"></Button>`

Where tc is equal to START-UP

The setup of my i18n.json file:

```
{
    "@COMMON": {
        "TITLE": "확정하다"
    },
    "START-UP": {
        "CONFIRM": "확정하다"
    }
}
```

WebpackConfig

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.+(jpg|png)" } },
                { from: { glob: "assets/**/*" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

Comment: Make sure your path to JSON is correct and your webpack bundle includes those JSON files.

Comment: @Manoj see update my i18n is located under assets so it's copied.

Comment: Did you try checking whether file exists programatically upon launch of the app?

Comment: @Manoj I check the Xcode build and it seems that copyWebpack isn't working

Comment: @Manoj I added the following rule `{ from: { glob: "assets/i18n/*.json"} }` to the `CopyWebPackPlugin` and now it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the following rule

`{ from: { glob: "assets/i18n/*.json"} }` to the WebpackConfig

So the Webpackconfig will look like this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.+(jpg|png)" } },
                { from: { glob: "assets/**/*" } },
                { from: { glob: "assets/i18n/*.json"} },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think absolute path not work correctly in *TranslateHttpLoader*.

Try to use relative path like this: TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/');

Comment: When I'm using that I'm getting the following error: ```"message": "Http failure response for ./assets/i18n/ko-KR.json: 0 Unknown Error"```

Comment: You need put your translation file like en-GB.json or ko-KR.json into folder /assets/i18n

Comment: Like you can see I added my i18n translations under the following folder: `src/assets/i18n/`